# Why is constraint optimization referred to as "X programming"?

Tags: terminology, constraint-programming

In many cases, constraint optimization will be referred to as some sort of "programming" like linear programming or quadratic programming. Why is this?

Comment: To program means to plan, and optimization problems arise when planning expending and management of some resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have to do with computer programs. The word "programming" is used in the sense of "planning" -- think of the *program* for a party or event, for example.

Some of the earliest motivating examples for optimization theory were about moving (military) supplies between producers and users, through warehouses and vehicles of limited capacity. The outcome of solving the problem was a concrete *program* for how stuff would be moved around, which trucks to send where at which time, etc.

Comment: Thanks Henning! Great response.

Comment: Some historical context: according to http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html the term "linear programming" dates to a paper by Dantzig from 1948, and the use of "programming" to refer to instructions to feed a computing machine dates to a paper from 1946. In both of these cases "program" arguably means a collection of instructions for what to do (whether the thing doing is the military or a computer).